# open cart version 1.5.6.1 reward points not showing in discount tab and all

Tags: opencart

I have installed Open cart version 1.5.6.1. When I am Trying to put products in a page  in that Product tab I want to give Reward Points For each and every Product! **Products->Discount-> reward Points..** This is the way to install products. Now i want to know How to add reward points in discount tab! Please reply your answer

Comment: question is unclear, discount and reward points both are separate feature, you are showing reward points inside the discount ?

Comment: Because in old version in open cart it shown! thats y asking!